# How to quick sort an array of pointers to structures in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, quicksort

So there are lots of examples of using `qsort()` with structures, pointers, etc. But none of them seem to sort correctly in my implementation.

This is an overview of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
  int value;
};
typedef struct node Node;

int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2);

int main()
{
    Node *myArray[10];
    Node *node1, *node2, *node3;
    int i;

    node1 = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node1->value = 10;
    myArray[0] = node1;

    node2 = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node2->value = 7;
    myArray[1] = node2;

    node3 = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node3->value = 12;
    myArray[2] = node3;

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("Element %i: %i\n", i, myArray[i]->value);
    }

    printf("-------------\n");

    qsort(myArray, 3, sizeof(Node*), compare);

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("Element %i: %i\n", i, myArray[i]->value);
    }

    return 0;
}

int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    Node *node1 = (Node*) p1;
    Node *node2 = (Node*) p2;

    return node1->value - node2->value;
}
```

*This code is to demonstrate my issue, so please don't have a rant at me for semantics! The extra unused space in the array is intentional. :p*

So as far as I'm aware, and from what I'm reading online, this should work. But it doesn't. For some reason it starts sorting through garbage values in the compare function.

I require the array to often be larger than the values within it, so hoped the second argument of the `qsort()` function would limit it to only the first 3 elements in this case. But it seems to be ignoring that.

Any ideas what's causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: I think p1 does not point at the node, but rather at the array element, i.e. the pointer to the node. You might need to doubly dereference p1 and p2.

Comment: That code won't compile.

Comment: Your code does not compile. `node->occurrences` is not defined and `main` is incomplete and `compare` is declared too late. And it should print the nodes at the end. Ultimately using `-` as a comparison operator makes no sense, but I can't tell if that's a bug or deliberate. Fix the code so it compiles and demonstrates the problem, please.

Comment: @user3420034 My mistake about the `-`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167092/qsort-and-bsearch-an-array-of-pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Joachim has solved one problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34164924/14660), there's another.  `qsort` passes *pointers* to the array elements to `compare` *even if they are already pointers*.  So `compare` is getting `Node **`, a double pointer.  You can see this if you print `node->value` inside `compare`.

Cast accordingly.

```
static int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const Node *node1 = *(const Node **)p1;
    const Node *node2 = *(const Node **)p2;

    printf("cmp %d %d\n", node1->value, node2->value);
    return node1->value - node2->value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you pass `*myArray` as the first argument to the `qsort` function, it's like passing `myArray[0]`, which is definitely not the correct pointer (and will lead to *undefined behavior* and most likely some weird behavior like sorting "garbage" data).

Either let the array decay to a pointer to the first element by using plain `myArray`, or explicitly specify the first element using `&myArray[0]`.