# Sorting strings in a program - C

Tags: c, gcc

So I'm trying to make a program that takes in certain number of strings from stdin and then output into a text file.
The code I have so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmpstr(const void * a, const void *b){
    const char* aa = (const char*) a;
    const char* bb = (const char*) b;
    return strcmp (aa, bb);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int i =0;
  int scount;
  char ** data = NULL;
  FILE * ofile;




if (argc != 3){
printf("%s \n", "The format to use this is: mySort <#of strings> <output filename>",argv[0]);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

scount = atoi(argv[1]);
if(!scount){
printf("%s \n", "Invalid number.");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

data = (char **) malloc(scount * sizeof(char*));
if(NULL == data){   
printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for(i = 0; i< scount; i++){
if(NULL == fgets(data[i], (int) sizeof(data), stdin)){
printf("Could not get line\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
}

qsort(data, scount, sizeof(char*), cmpstr);

ofile = fopen(argv[2], "w+");
if(ofile == NULL){
printf("Could not open output file. \n");
}   

for(i = 0; i<scount; i++){
    fputs(data[i], ofile);
}

fclose(ofile);

for(i=0; i<scount; i++){
    if(data[i]) free(data[i]);
}

if (data) free(data);

exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);

return 0;
}
```

However, when I compiled it it gave me a segmentation fault. I tried using the gdb debugger to try and debug it but it did not give me anything really and I barely understand how to use gdb. But my takeaway from the usage of gdb is that there is not enough memory allocated which confuses me since I allocated memory using malloc.

Comment: When you compiled it segfaulted? Or after you compiled and then ran it?

Comment: segmentation fault happened after I compiled it and ran it

Comment: Which line caused the segfault?

Comment: @ZCode ask yourself, where does `data[i]` point to in your fgets line?

Comment: `const char* bb = (const char*) a;` is odd.

Comment: Totally missed that... But the pointers are still to `char *` not `char`

Comment: What warnings do you get if you compile with -Wall -Wextra?

Comment: OT why is cmpstr declared inside main? The second should be b, not a, BTW.

Comment: @chux yet, had to reevaluate, the pointers are pointers to `char *` so you need something similar to `return strcmp (*(char * const *)a, *(char * const *)b);` Additionally, the `'{'` scope is all mucked up. C doesn't 'allow nested functions.

Comment: @Bob__ -- not OT at all. That's a big part of "Why won't this compile?"

Comment: @PeterT Does data[i] not point to the newly allocated memory? Unless its pointing to NULL

Comment: This is a goodness only knows how many times duplicate.  When you sort an array of `int`, the comparator is passed two `int *` values disguised as `void *`.  When you sort an array of `char *`, the comparator is passed two `char **` values disguised as `void *`.  You need to fix `cmpstr()`: `int cmpstr(const void * a, const void *b) {
    const char* aa = *(char **)a;
    const char* bb = *(char **)b;
    return strcmp(aa, bb);
}`

Comment: Note the comments attached to the second answer in the duplicate — added while deciding whether to use it as the duplicate for this question (and echoing my previous comment here).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The proposed duplicates are about the second problem. But before reaching the second problem, there's the first problem, which has nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: @Gilles: You mean that there are also other problems, not just the sorting code which is bogus because of the faulty comparator.  I suppose that shouldn't be a surprise, but when it is clear that the comparator is wrong, I like to think that it is the cause of the trouble.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I mean that the faulty comparator is never even called, since the memory for the data that's to be compared isn't allocated. So whether you like it or not, it isn't what ZCode has been struggling with and trying to understand in gdb so far. It's ridiculous to offer those questions as duplicates: they won't help ZCode solve their problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And yes, over the years somebody has probably posted a question about running a similar problem while allocating an array of strings. If you can find it (I couldn't), then close this question as a duplicate of *that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> data = (char **) malloc(scount * sizeof(char*));
> ```

Here you allocate memory for an array of pointers. You never initialize the contents of that array. Therefore, when you access `data[0]` below by passing it to `fgets`, you're accessing an uninitialized pointer object. If you're lucky, the contents of that uninitialized memory constitutes an invalid address, and when `fgets` attempts to store data there, your program crashes. If you're unlucky, the contents of that uninitialized memory happens to be the address of some block of memory that's used by some other object and you get memory corruption that's really hard to debug.

You need to initialize the pointers allocated by malloc. Like any other pointer object, depending on what you want to do, you can initialize them to NULL, to a pointer to an existing object, or to the result of calling a function such as `malloc`. In this program, you need to obtain storage for the lines that you're going to read, therefore you'll need to call `malloc` on each of the lines. Since you don't know in advance how long a line will be, this is best done at the time you read the line.

It would be a good idea to first set all the elements to NULL, as soon as you've allocated the array of pointers, and later allocate memory for the individual lines. You don't have to, but it's easier then to keep track of which elements of the array have been initialized and which ones haven't. In particular, that lets you call `free` on all the array elements without having to worry how many you've already reached.

> ```
> fgets(data[i], (int) sizeof(data), stdin)
> ```

Passing `sizeof(data)` here doesn't make sense. The variable `data` is a pointer to `char*`, so `sizeof(data)` is just the size of a pointer. It isn't the size of the array that the pointer points to: that size isn't known at compile time, it's the argument you pass to `malloc`. And even that size is not relevant here: the size is the maximum number of lines you can read (multiplied by the size of a pointer to a line's contents), but what `fgets` needs is the size of the memory that's allocated for the line.

To keep things simple, let's say you have a maximum line length `max_line_length`.

```
data = (char **) malloc(scount * sizeof(char*));
if (data == NULL) ... // omitted error checking
for (i = 0; i < scount; i++)
    data[i] = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < scount; i++) {
    data[i] = malloc(max_line_length+2); // +2 for line break character and null byte to terminate the string
    if (data[i] == NULL) ... // omitted error checking
    if(NULL == fgets(data[i], max_line_length, stdin)) ... // omitted error checking
    ...
}
```

After this you'll run into another issue as described in the comments, in that `cmpstr` receives pointers to pointers to line contents, not pointers to line contents. This is explained in [How to qsort an array of pointers to char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489139/how-to-qsort-an-array-of-pointers-to-char-in-c)

Comment: If you want to initialize the pointers to NULL anyway, you could alternatively use `calloc`...

Comment: @Aconcagua In practice, yes, but technically, no: `calloc` allocates all-bits-zero and there are rare platforms where this is not a null pointer (imagine a platform with RAM or ROM mapped at all-bits-zero).

Comment: Thank you sir. People have been pointing out that cmpstr which was wrong but an easy fix but they did not realize I was struggling more on the memory aspect of it.